# Ez Publish 5- Add TinyMCE plugin

Tags: tinymce-4, ezpublish

Is somewhere  tutorial  how to add new  pluging  for TinyMCE in eZ Publish 5 ?
Any  link to source  or explanation  would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version, the following guides might be relevant:
http://share.ez.no/blogs/sebastiaan-van-der-vliet/adding-a-custom-button-to-the-online-editor/(language)/eng-GB
or
http://www.contextualcode.com/Blog/Extending-RichText-field-type-in-eZ-Platform

Comment: Thank you for reply!
Nop, it isn't what i want , i want tutorial where is a explanation how to add  new plugin  not a button in existing plugin.